# How to get input from command line in a simple bash file?

Tags: bash, shell

I think this is the worst error I have ever seen. I have written what I have seen also here:

[Example of script](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0110.php) but continuously I get error. My plan is to see how read command works. But it seems a dodgy error in my code or terminal. I wondered if anyone has seen similar problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Plz enter"
read  text
echo "You entered $text"
echo $text
echo "$text"
```

Error:

```
$ . test.sh 
Plz enter
b
': not a valid identifier
You entered 


$
```

Comment: what's the output of  'which bash' command

Comment: on linux and mac (shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I had the same error in windows with cygwin, I fixed it changing the end of line format from windows format to unix format.

You can also convert the end of line format using `Notepad++: Edit > EOL Conversion > UNIX`, then save and run the file.

Answer (score 2):

Your input file contains CR+LF [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Remove those and the script should work well.  You could use `dos2unix` or any other utility to remove the CR.

Comment: mmm...CR + LF please give minor details for a Noob... :)

Comment: @NoobEditor The link in the answer should help, I suppose.

Comment: yup...even i found same link searcing for it!! :)

Comment: meanwhile...you never told me, how a 94 year old *dev null* can answer so precisly!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor Perhaps because of the age!

Answer (score 0):

I think, try to change the shell path as like below!

```
root@sathish:/tmp# vim test.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Plz enter"
read  text
echo "You entered $text"
echo $text
echo "$text"

root@sathish:/tmp# chmod +x test.sh 
root@sathish:/tmp# ./test.sh 
-bash: ./test.sh: /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

root@sathish:/tmp# which bash
/bin/bash

root@sathish:/tmp# ls /usr/bin/bash
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory

root@sathish:/tmp# vim test.sh 

#!/bin/bash
echo "Plz enter"
read  text
echo "You entered $text"
echo $text
echo "$text"

root@sathish:/tmp# ./test.sh 
Plz enter
a
You entered a
a
a
```